# Estimating change in y on a $P=x^2+0.1xy+y^2$, so that we can decrease input of x by 0.5 with P unchanged, given at certain period x=10, y= 8

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Full question:

> The production $P$ of a company satisfies the equation $P=x^2+0.1xy+y^2$
> where $x$ and $y$ are the inputs. At a certain period $x=10$ units and $ y=8$
> units. Estimate the change in $y$ that should be made to set up a
> decrease of $0.5$ in the input $x$ so that the production remains the
> same.

> [Possible Ans: $0.3, 0.61$ or none of the above]

I tried setting it up using implicit differentiation in respect to time [t] but seem unsuccessful, which results me to thinking the answer is "none of the above". Am I correct?

1. If you can tell me a gap in my knowledge based on my writing that'd be great
2. Otherwise can you show me how you'd do this question please?

[image]

Comment: check your working: $\dfrac{dP}{dt} = (2x + 0.1y) \dfrac{dx}{dt} + (2y + 0.1x) \dfrac{dy}{dt}$ and you should get $\approx 0.61$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P=x^2+\frac{xy}{10}+y^2$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+\frac{xy}{10}+y^2)$

Since production remains same therefore change in it will be $0$

$0=20x\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}+20y\frac{dy}{dt}$

Plugging values gives

$20*8*\frac{dy}{dt}+8*(-0.5)+10*\frac{dy}{dt}+20*10*(-0.5)=0$

$160*\frac{dy}{dt}-4+10*\frac{dy}{dt}-100=0$

$170\frac{dy}{dt}-104=0$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{104}{170}=\frac{52}{85}$

Now Since questioner wants to know difference between mine and @Tavish's approach, I have following to tell

See here $P$ depends on two factors $x$ and $y$.
. According to question we want to find the rate by which y should change ,when x changes by the rate of -0.5, so that P doesn't change. When we do $dP/dt$ we take in account the rate of change of $P$ when both $x$ and $y$ change so It helps us to get a single equation.

When we do $\partial P/\partial x$ we take in account the rate by which P will be changing when only x changes. When we do $\partial P/\partial y$ we take in account the rate by which P will be changing when only y changes.

You know that

Change in P when both x and y change = Change in P when only x changes + Change in P when only y changes

Change in P when only x changes= rate of change of P when only x changes($\partial P/\partial x$) * change in x

similarly

Change in P when only y changes= rate of change of P when only y changes($\partial P/\partial y$) * change in y

Comment: What do you think about @tavish 's comment about us needing to take $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y} * -0.5$ ? Yours is one of the answer, so I'm inclined to think your answer is correct. Could you or anyone else help me evaluate tavish's suggestion?

Comment: Yes his answer is correct and I'm able to understand it.

Comment: see here $dP/dt $ is to be zero when both: x and y are changed

Comment: So the approach is different..? Is there a way you can help summarise @tavish's vs your approach to help me understand it better?

Comment: but $\partial P/\partial x$ represents rate of change of P when only x changes and y doesn't

Comment: yes I am editing my answer

Comment: Doesn't the formula for $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y}$ account for any/all possible values of x or y already? Or does Implicit differentiation apply differently from explicit differentiation that way?...

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It's clear now that you and I are taking P in terms of t(time), while @tavish is using P in terms of x. // However it is not clear why the change in P in terms of x should multiply the change in x. (ie. $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y} * -0.5$) ..... // .... The equation tavish sets up: $c\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} -0.5 \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} does not make logical sense to me. What is c? reading it verbatim makes it more confusing: "c * P in terms of x - change in x * P in terms of y is 0."

Comment: @nvs0000 Look at edit change in P when only x changes = rate of change of P when only x changes * change in x

Comment: Also If my answer helped you please accept it

Comment: Yes your answer definitely helped me and accepted it.. Why would we take the "change of P when only x changes * change in x"? Reading it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Have you understood that net change in P when both x and y are changing = change in P when only x is changing(y constant)+ change in P when only y is changing(x constant+

Comment: Yes, if there's change in both x and y I can see there'd be a net change in P. I suspect my knowledge gap is understanding what $-0.5 \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$ means. Perhaps I need a full worked out sum with explanation of @tavish's workings.

Comment: Wait Let me explain

Comment: @nvs0000 now tell me what will be the change in P in 1 second when only x changes provided that you know the "rate of change" of P when only x changes and change in x in 1 second

Comment: I'm not sure I'm able to tell you as the question doesn't state anywhere that the -0.5 decrease is based on 1 second?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

When you change $x$ by $-0.5$, the change in $P$ is given by $$ -0.5 \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} $$ Similarly, when you change $y$ by $c$, $P$ changes by $$c \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} $$ You want these changes to cancel out, i.e. $$c\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} -0.5 \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} =0$$ and you can solve for $c$.

Here, e.g. $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} $ denotes the partial derivative of $P$ w.r.t $x$ at $(10,8)$.

Comment: Puzzling. Given the equation, wouldn't $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y}$ be 0, since the question asked for P to remain the same? Why would we multiple "change in P" by -0.5?

Comment: @nvs0000 No, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ is the change in $P$ when one changes $y$, **keeping $x$ constant**. The net change is obtained by adding both changes. So, the change in $P$ w.r.t $x$ is not $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$, but $-0.5$ times it.

Comment: @nvs0000 I had posted an answer to point out your mistake but I deleted it and added a comment. That should lead you to the right answer. But by definition, what you are doing is not correct. It does not tell you anywhere that $x, y$ are function of $t$. Change in $x$ can be instantaneous. So you should really go by this answer.

Comment: Actually wouldn't $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y}$ be the formula for any x or y value, regardless of x and y variables being constant?
// Also @Lalit Tolani's answer seems correct and didn't assume $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y}* -0.5$ ..? I won't know how to do it by multiplying change in P by -0.5. This is from a calculus 1 class. Did your answer result in 52/85 or ~0.61 too?

Comment: @nvs0000 You are not multiplying change in P by -0.5. You are multiplying -0.5(change in x in 1 second) to the" rate of change" in P when only x changes to get the" change" in P when only x changes

Comment: Ok i get that we are multiplying rate of change of x by P in terms of x. But what is is, what does P in terms of x multiplied by the rate of change of x give us? Why is this value $-0.5 \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$ helpful?

Comment: @nvs0000 It did, of course. No, I only stated the definition of $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$. You’re missing my point again. I did *not* multiply the change in $P$ by $-0.5$, but $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$ (rate of change) .Multiplying  this rate by $-0.5$ gives the change in $P$.